# Help needed making Random Permutations in R studio

Tags: r

I am very new to R and struggling a bit with getting my head around things.

I need to make random permutations out of my data set, I have 5 categories (these are age classes) 10, 16, 21, 26, 36. These 5 categories are arranged into sightings of groups... for example, (for about 2000 groups):

```
10,10,16,21

16,16,16

36

21

21,26

21,10

10,10,16

16

21

26, 16

16,16,16,16,21,16,10

16,21,16

26
```

I need to make random permutations of these groups. Keeping the same number of values of each age class (10,16,21,26,36) and keeping same the number of each group size (e.g in example above still have 5 groups with just 1 member, 3 groups of 3 members)

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to read the data, generate one random permutation and, optionally, save it to a file.

```
library("tidyverse")

input <- "10,10,16,21
16,16,16
36
21
21,26
21,10
10,10,16
16
21
26,16
16,16,16,16,21,16,10
16,21,16
26
"

read_data <- function(input) {
  data <-
    read_lines(input) %>%  # Or read them from a text file with `read_lines(filename)`
    enframe("group", "category") %>% # Convert to a data frame with two columns:
                                     # "name": the group ID, which is the same as the row number
                                     # "value": the sequence of sightings as a string
    mutate(category = str_split(category, ",")) %>%  # Split "10,16,26" into c("10","16","26"), etc.
    unnest() %>%           # "Unfold" the data frame so that each row is a group ID and an element
                           # e.g., c("10","16","26") will unnest into three rows.
    mutate(category = as.integer(category))    # Convert "10" into 10, might not be strictly necessary
  data
}

permute_data <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(shuffled = sample(category, n(), replace = FALSE)) %>%  # Keep the IDs ordered,
                                                                 # shuffle the observations.
    group_by(group) %>%                             # Now a group originally with 3 elements is
    summarise(shuffled = paste(shuffled, collapse = ",")) # matched with 3 randomly selected elements.
                                                          # Join those together in the input format.
}

data <- read_data(input)
data2 <- permute_data(data) # Permute the data, once or multiple times

# The result is a data frame with the original groups in the "name" column,
# and the shuffled groups in the "shuffled" column
data2

data2$shuffled %>% write_lines("shuffled.txt")  # Save just the shuffled column to a new file.
```

Comment: Hi dipetkov!


Thanks so much for getting back to me, this all looks really useful will have a go now. I've been thinking about my problem for some hours now, Is it also possible to do it this slightly different method?


Say I know in total I have 470 of the category "10", 1100 of "16", 440 of the category "21", 240 of the category "26", 54 of the category "36" ... and I know I need to randomly distribute these categories among 720 groups of size 1, 503 groups of size 2, 77 groups of size 3, 68 groups of size 4 etc.... 

do you have any recommendations for doing it via this method?

Comment: Perhaps it is a question of how you express your idea in code? What the code does is pretty much the same as your idea: The data frame has one column that contains information about the number of groups and the size of each group, and another column that contains information about the categories and the number of sightings of each category. I've renamed these columns "group" and "category" to be more explicit. We start with "group" and "category" aligned so that the table represents the original data. Then we shuffle one column and not the other and the new alignment is a permutation.

Comment: Hi dipetkov! 
This worked perfectly thanks for your help. 
Could you help me with one more thing? At the end you explain the final running of the permutation, and then explain "data2 <- permute_data(data) # Permute the data, once or multiple times" ... I think I need to run the permutation some 100 times or so, I tried to run a replicate code but had no luck - would you have a suggestion here for making replicates?

Comment: You can generate 100 permutations with a for loop:
```for (i in 1:100) {
  perm <- permute_data(data);
  # Do something with that permutation....;
  # For example you can print to see that they are all indeed different;
  print(perm)
}``` Is that what you mean by replicates?

Comment: Yes thanks this is what I meant, but how do I save all 100 of these random permutations? `for (i in 1:100) { perm <- permute_data(data)
 print(perm) }` just gives me 100 versions of perm, but perm as a data set is still only as long as the original data set re-shuffled? I want to have all 100 permutations available to extract? Thanks so much again

Comment: You can use `write_csv` but you have to give each file a different name or R will overwrite one and the same file. For example, `write_lines(glue("shuffled{i}.txt"))`. Load the glue package with `library("glue")` at the start.

Comment: Thanks dipetkov, but still having trouble getting this to work - with error message  `write_lines(glue("shuffled{i}.txt"))
Error in standardise_path(path, input = FALSE) : 
  argument "path" is missing, with no default` ... could you perhaps edit the original reply with the complete code? I'm just trying to get end result of table with 100 or so repeats of this permutation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough. Try `perm %>% write_lines(glue("shuffled{i}.txt"))` -- this uses a pipe `%>%` to "send" the `perm` tibble for writing. Or equivalently, `write_lines(perm, "shuffled{i}.txt")`.

Comment: It might be also helpful to know how to look up the documentation for a function (in RStudio). Try `?write_lines` or `help(write_lines)`.